# Laravel Swagger - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: laravel, swagger

I am getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" in console when trying to generate the Swagger documentation. Page is black and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" in console.

I am using

Laravel 5.7 
darkaonline/l5-swagger": "5.7.*
zircote/swagger-php": "2.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit strange

just removing extra spaced from the code fixed the issue.

resources/views/vendor/l5-swagger/index.blade.php

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',

    url: "{!! $urlToDocs !!}",
    operationsSorter: {!! isset($operationsSorter) ? '"' . $operationsSorter . '"' : 'null' !!},
    configUrl: {!! isset($configUrl) ? '"' . $configUrl . '"' : 'null' !!},
    validatorUrl: {!! isset($validatorUrl) ? '"' . $validatorUrl . '"' : 'null' !!},
    oauth2RedirectUrl: "{{ route('l5-swagger.oauth2_callback') }}",
    requestInterceptor: function() {
      this.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
      return this;
    },
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  });
  window.ui = ui;
}
</script>
```